how to force readr to read the first column as character and guess all other columns
I would like to read tab-delimited-files with readr::read_tsv.
The files have columnheaders for all columns, except for the first column which header is empty.
The data in the first column contains mixed datatypes (numbers and text).
How can i force readr to read the first column as character and guess all other columns?
Thanks a lot!

"Column which header is empty"―usually these are row names. Have you tried read.table('your.tsv') which can read row names?

If all else fails, which it won't :-) ,  just read it all in and do as.character(my_data[,1]

Here is a relevant snippet from the help page of readr::read_tsv() for the col_types argument:

If NULL, all column types will be inferred from guess_max rows of the input, interspersed throughout the file. This is convenient (and fast), but not robust. If the guessed types are wrong, you'll need to increase guess_max or supply the correct types yourself.

Therefore, readr::read_tsv() should be able to guess the first column should be character by default so long as it observes the mixed data within the first guess_max rows. In the event this does not work you might either increase the value for the guess_max argument or instead specify how columns should be read via the col_types argument.
Default example
In this example, the mixed data of the first column are observed within the first guess_max = min(1000, n_max) where n_max = Inf by default so within the first 1,000 rows and the column is read in as character as desired.
library(readr)

f <- tempfile(fileext = ".tsv")

writeLines(
  c(
    "\ty\tz",
    "1\t2\tc",
    "d\t5\tf",
    "7\t8\ti"
  ),
  f
)

read_tsv(f)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>   ...1      y z    
#>   <chr> <dbl> <chr>
#> 1 1         2 c    
#> 2 d         5 f    
#> 3 7         8 i

Failure to guess first column correctly
In this example, we change the value of guess_max to prevent observing the mixed data of the first column and the column is read in as double which is not desired.
read_tsv(f, guess_max = 1)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>    ...1     y z    
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
#> 1     1     2 c    
#> 2    NA     5 f    
#> 3     7     8 i

Use of col_types
If the guess for the first column is wrong, and we don't want to mess with guess_max, we need to make use of the col_types argument. There are a few ways to use this argument. Here we use the compact string representation where each character represents one column with "c" representing character and "?" representing guess.
read_tsv(f, col_types = "c??", guess_max = 1)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>   ...1      y z    
#>   <chr> <dbl> <chr>
#> 1 1         2 c    
#> 2 d         5 f    
#> 3 7         8 i

Created on 2024-06-23 with reprex v2.1.0.9000

@ the-mad-statter. thanks a lot for your detailed answer.
